# Programmatically adding images to media library

Tags: images, attachments, media-library

I am trying to programmatically add multiple images to media library, I uploaded the images to `wp-content/uploads`, now I try to use `wp_insert_attachement`.

Here's the code, however it's not working as expected, I think metadata is not properly generated, I can see the files in media library, but without a thumbnail, also if I edit the image I get an error saying to re-upload the image.

```
$filename_array = array(
   'article1.jpg',
   'article2.jpg',
);

// The ID of the post this attachment is for.
$parent_post_id = 0;

// Get the path to the upload directory.
$wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

foreach ($filename_array as $filename) {

    // Check the type of file. We'll use this as the 'post_mime_type'.
    $filetype = wp_check_filetype( basename( $filename ), null );

    // Prepare an array of post data for the attachment.
    $attachment = array(
        'guid'           => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename( $filename ), 
        'post_mime_type' => $filetype['type'],
        'post_title'     => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $filename ) ),
        'post_content'   => '',
        'post_status'    => 'inherit'
    );

    // Insert the attachment.
    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filename, $parent_post_id );

    // Make sure that this file is included, as   wp_generate_attachment_metadata() depends on it.
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );

    // Generate the metadata for the attachment, and update the database record.
    $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $filename );
    wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );

}
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
$image_url = 'adress img';

$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

$image_data = file_get_contents( $image_url );

$filename = basename( $image_url );

if ( wp_mkdir_p( $upload_dir['path'] ) ) {
  $file = $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $filename;
}
else {
  $file = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' . $filename;
}

file_put_contents( $file, $image_data );

$wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype( $filename, null );

$attachment = array(
  'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
  'post_title' => sanitize_file_name( $filename ),
  'post_content' => '',
  'post_status' => 'inherit'
);

$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file );
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file );
wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
```

Comment: where is $attach_id coming from?

Comment: it was missing... i added it

Comment: File downloaded but no thumbnail available, attachment url also giving 404

Comment: @UmairHamid Same here. This is because the second argument of `wp_insert_attachment` should be the file path (so `$file` in this example), not the file name. I edited the answer, waiting for approval.

Comment: and how can I get the new url ?

Comment: it doesnt work, does anyone have the answer?

Comment: Use `wp_get_attachment_image_src` to get the URL, eg. `wp_get_attachment_image_src($attach_id)` - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src

Comment: how can I upload image as a file from computer and not as a URL?

Answer (score 15):

If you use WordPress' sideload feature, you can do this more easily (and have WordPress handle all of the sanitization for you).

```php
<?php
// example:
//   $file = 'http://www.example.com/image.png';
//   $description = 'some description';

function my_upload_image( $file, $description ) {
   $file_array  = [ 'name' => wp_basename( $file ), 'tmp_name' => download_url( $file ) ];

   // If error storing temporarily, return the error.
   if ( is_wp_error( $file_array['tmp_name'] ) ) {
    return $file_array['tmp_name'];
   }

   // Do the validation and storage stuff.
   $id = media_handle_sideload( $file_array, 0, $description );

   // If error storing permanently, unlink.
   if ( is_wp_error( $id ) ) {
    @unlink( $file_array['tmp_name'] );
       return $id;
   }

   return true;
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this only works from within `/wp-admin/`. Outside it you need to make sure to `require_once` these three files:
`ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php'`,
`ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php'`,
`ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php'`

Comment: This also works for images already stored on the server, you simply use the image path rather than `download_url( $file )`. But if you do this, please note that when using `media_handle_sideload`, it will automatically delete the image when processed. If you do not want this to happen, then simply copy the image to the tmp directory via `$tmp_path = get_temp_dir() . basename( $file ); copy( $file, $tmp_path );`, then you can use `'tmp_name' => $tmp_path` instead.

Answer (score 6):

I had issues with @TrubinE's solution where image files were not getting loaded.

Here is a complete example that worked for me: https://gist.github.com/m1r0/f22d5237ee93bcccb0d9

This is a similar idea but use the WP HTTP library to fetch the content versus file_get_contents().  Here is the content of the github gist solution from m1r0:

```
    if ( ! class_exists( 'WP_Http' ) ) {
        include_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-http.php' );
    }

    $http = new WP_Http();
    $response = $http->request( $meta['image_url'] );
    if ( $response['response']['code'] !== 200 ) {
        return false;
    }

    $upload = wp_upload_bits( basename( $meta['image_url'] ), null, $response['body'] );
    if ( !empty( $upload['error'] ) ) {
        return false;
    }
    $file_path = $upload['file'];
    $file_name = basename( $file_path );
    $file_type = wp_check_filetype( $file_name, null );
    $attachment_title = sanitize_file_name( pathinfo( $file_name, PATHINFO_FILENAME ) );
    $wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    
    $post_info = array(
        'guid'           => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . $file_name,
        'post_mime_type' => $file_type['type'],
        'post_title'     => $attachment_title,
        'post_content'   => '',
        'post_status'    => 'inherit',
    );
    
    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $post_info, $file_path, $parent_post_id );
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
    $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file_path );
    wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id,  $attach_data );
    return $attach_id; code here
```

Answer (score 0):

```
`<?php  
// simplest method upload image  
$url_image = "http://example.com/any_image.jpg" ;  
$new_image_id = upload_image_by_url ( $url_image );  

function upload_image_by_url ($url) {
    $title = basename($url) ; 
    $image_for_post_id = 0 ; // 0 means the image is not associated with the post 
    $imgid = media_sideload_image( $url, $image_for_post_id, $title, 'id' );  
    if ( is_wp_error($imgid) ) {  
        echo "<br>Error upload_image_by_url($url): ";
        echo $imgid->get_error_message();
        return false;  
    }  
    else {  
        echo "<br>upload_image_by_url($url) = $imgid";
        return $imgid;
    }
}?>`
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That looks like it's the same basic approach as Paul's answers. Do the comments there apply here too, e.g. about deleting failed uploads?